# How can I parse an XML document that requires tags with illegal characters using XmlDocument?

Tags: c#, .net, xml, winforms, xmldocument

I'm designing a save-data editing application using Windows Forms and C#

The save data is stored in simple un-indexed XML files (savegame.xml)
Everything in my save editor is working, however, these save data files contain a tag called "reward" which is filled with tags that contain numbers as tag names:

```xml
<reward>
    <1000 value="1"/>
    <2000 value="1"/>
    <3000 value="1"/>
</reward>
```

The application that uses this save data has a "Custom" XML parser that supports numbers in tag names.
The issue is that the default `XmlDocument` in windows form's C# does support numbers in tag names (Likewise with pretty much any other XML parser out there)
So, this tiny tag collection at the bottom of the file is crashing the entire application.
Is it possible to "ignore" these rules and continue on?

Furthermore, is it possible to use `XmlDocument`'s `XmlDocument.CreateElement()` to create those same elements with numbers for tag names?

**The program requires these** (Otherwise it doesn't accept the save file as valid)

The only thing I can think of to get around it, is to simply delete it from the raw text, edit the XML with `XmlDocument` and then save it, placing the reward tags back in afterwards manually..

Code I use to grab the save data which is causing the error:

```cs
var fileName = Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData), "Teardown\\savegame.xml");
XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
using (StreamReader xmlSr = new StreamReader(fileName, true))
{
    xmlDoc.Load(xmlSr);
}
```

Example error from one of my attempts:

```
An unhandled exception of type 'System.Xml.XmlException' occurred in System.Xml.dll
Name cannot begin with the '2' character, hexadecimal value 0x32. Line 283, position 5.
```

Comment: That's not XML so you can't use `XmlDocument`. Try an SGML or lenient-HTML parser like [`HTML Agility pack`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/846994/).

Comment: Well, a possible workaround is use Regex to replace `\<\d+` by a valid tag, do your processing, and undo the replace.

Comment: @Magnetron Could you elaborate? Id rather not switch to that "HTML Agility Pack" package suggested.. Because ive already written a massive program built around XmlDocument. Id appreciate if you could show me how to "undo" the replace after I make edits.

Comment: @RandomWebDev well, I'm not sure that is the only problem with your file, since `<1000 value="1">` is also not closed, so I don't think `XmlDocument` or `XDocument` would parse it correctly.

Comment: But what I have suggested was using regex to change your input to something like `<myfaketag original-tag="1000" value="1">` and then, after processing, use Regex again to revert to the original form.

Comment: @Magnetron Thanks. If you want to write that into an answer Ill accept it so you atleast get some rep from your help. PS: Those tags are closed, Im just stupid and kinda forgot to close them myself while writing the question.

Comment: Have you tried wrapping the numeric tags in a <![CDATA[]]> section?

Comment: There are no illegal characters in your element names, however element names are prohibited from starting with a digit.  See duplicate link for how to deal with not well-formed "XML".

Comment: By all means invent your own angle-bracket language if you must, but please don't call it XML, or expect to process it using XML software.

Comment: @MichaelKay Its XML... It just so happens that is has badly formatted tags near the bottom. The extension specifies it aswell ".xml".. Changing text in a tag doesnt magically change the language, and I never said I wanted to invent my own language. I actually mentioned this issue to the developer of the app Im making a save editor for, and he mentioned that they shouldnt be using those tags, and that they would most likely be fixed anyhow in another update.

Comment: It's no more XML than `9f [o**^(&T(GOUKBKFiwefgI` is XML.

Comment: @MichaelKay Ok, well, it seems you care more about making a joke out of me. This isnt helpful to me at all, nor to the question. (I doubt you even care anyhow). Im an idiot... and comparing spam to slightly misformatted XML is just.. well... childish.

Comment: Sorry, but as far as an XML parser is concerned, the slightest syntax error makes the data into complete garbage. It's like submitting a Java program with a syntax error: it doesn't matter how gross the error is, the code isn't going to run. Tiny errors are just as bad as major errors. I'm sorry you regard my contribution as unhelpful, it's not designed to belittle you, it's just telling you the facts.